# options for renderDataTable ignored

Tags: r, shiny

The options for renderDataTable in Shiny is not working. This is what I used. The

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {   
     dataInput <- reactive({input$text})
     output$table1 <- renderDataTable({(options = list(pageLength = 10))
```

The table always displays a default length of 25. I would like the length to be 7,6,8,9,10

Comment: First of all your `renderDataTable` is missing the data :) Moreover I couldn't reproduce the problem. Could you provide session info? Finally  `shiny::renderDataTable` is  deprecated. You should use `DT::renderDataTable` instead.

Comment: @zero323 - Thanks. That worked after I added this as a parameter. You can answer this question and I will accept it. output$table1 <- renderDataTable(fn1(dataInput()), 
                                     options = list(pageLength=7))